# In the answer "look for a new job" used too often?

Tags: discussion

Very often this answer is given, and sometimes it is clear that it is not the answer the OP is looking for.

How to deal with this? Flag or downvote or is it just ok as an answer, even if it's generic?

Comment: Flag every time someone puts it as a response.  That way, companies can have plenty of unhappy workers.

Comment: Unless the OP specifically mentions that leaving isn't an option, how could you know that it's "not the answer the OP is looking for"?

Comment: Related: [Is 'Quit your job' an acceptable answer?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1692)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is 'Quit your job' an acceptable answer?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/is-quit-your-job-an-acceptable-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's easy to answer the question, "is "X" used too often?" because I don't think there's a black or white, yes or no answer for most questions on here - which makes it hard to judge overuse. Clearly, there are situations that call for immediately looking for another job. But there are also situations where "switch jobs" just ends up as the easy way out, versus learning/growing/changing a challenging situation.

Probably more common than either of those situations are cases where the OP hasn't given enough detail, or is leaving out important factors, either unintentionally or because of their own perspectives on what answers are feasible. When we're only getting part of a story, a quick black/white answer is a reasonable reaction.

One of the benefits of the Stack Exchange format for a topic like The Workplace is that we can collect lots of answers, and even when one becomes popular, or gets flagged as the accepted answer, the other answers can remain and add value for future readers.

Hence, when I see a question where I get a gut feeling that a "canned" or "easy way out" answer is being "over used," I try to sit back and think about other perspectives, or nuances that are over looked, and answer based on that. Or, I ask clarifying questions in comments instead of answering. This gives the OP and the community another perspective to consider and may help the community self-regulate in terms of recognizing over-use of certain answers.

Answer (score 0):

Oh for FOX sake no.

Who is going to make the call on when "look for a new job" is a good answer?

Are we going to have guidelines as to when it's okay to use that as an answer?  Suspensions for people who do?

If you don't like the fact that people are answering in a certain way, sit down, take some time and write a better one yourself.

Should we not tell someone who is being harassed to get another job?

Someone who is in a dangerous work environment?

Someone who has been financially damaged?

Someone falsely accused?

Someone who is burned out to the point of having a breakdown?
.

.

For many situations it is an answer and a legitimate answer.  In any situation where there is some strife, I always advise to update your resume and be ready to move on.

Now, we've had the debate over the "just quit" response a few times and even THAT is not an inappropriate response in all matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm letting my other answer stand, but adding this one.

I would assert that it's not used **ENOUGH**

Why?

Your resume should always be updated and you should always be ready to move quickly because things can go south very quickly.  While I don't think "Look for a new job" should be the entirety of an answer, it should be part of many of them, if not most.

It is a VERY appropriate answer for anything that involves interpersonal conflict that cannot be resolved at a managerial level.

IF:

- Management won't do anything
- HR won't do anything
- Sr management or "C" level executives are aware and no nothing
- It involves legal entanglements

Moving on should be part of the advice.

Comment: Given how disruptive it can be to switch jobs, and the chance that you'd be hopping from frying pan to fire, I appreciate the concept of criteria to qualify "get another job" advice. I'd add another bullet: *If you've thoroughly examined your own role in the conflict and have legitimately tried through your own means to resolve things.* I know, personally, that it's possible to run from a problem that in hindsight may have been solve-able, and as much as switching jobs is the easy way out of a given problem, it doesn't inherently solve the problem so much as avoid it.

Comment: @dwizum good point, and it varies by industry.  In IT, it's far less disruptive to move on, and so many people do it, most interviewers won't plumb too deeply.  Still, if a situation is intractable, and the writing is on the wall, move on.